# Adding placemarks to ERDAS APOLLO maps

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, gis

I want to allow users to add placemark in maps.
I m using JBoss, [ERAS APOLLO](http://www.hexagongeospatial.com/products/provider-suite/erdas-apollo) and JSPs.
How can i do this???

Comment: I assume you are talking about this?  http://www.erdas.com/products/ERDASAPOLLO/ERDASAPOLLOEssentials-ImageWebServer/Details.aspx

Comment: yes i m using ERDASAPOLLO server and want to add functionality of placemarkers in it... How can i do so??? which library and functions should be used???